# Using a NDSolve inside a user defined function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
 fun[y1_, y2_, ti_, w_] := 
 Module[{y1i = y1, y2i = y2, tj = ti, wi = w}, a = 0.5; b = 0.8; 
 c = 1.5;
 t1 = tj; t2 = tj + wi;
 Ans = Y /. 
 First@NDSolve[{Y'[t] = a*Y[t] + b*X[t], X'[t] = c*Y[t] + a*X[t], 
    Y[t1] = y1i, X[t1] = y2i}, {Y, X}, {t, t1, t2} ];
 Data = Table[{t, Ans[t]}, {t, t1, t2, 10^-6}]; 
 Export["Data.xls", Data, "XLS"]
 ya = Ans["ValuesOnGrid"]
 Return[Last[ya]];];
 fun[1, 0, 0, 1]`
```

I have been trying to solve similar coupled differential equations in Mathematica. So far I have been able to do this outside the a defined function and was able to use the data for analysis purposes. But for using inside loops, I need to solve coupled differential equations numerically inside functions.

Comment: every line needs a semicolon to terminate.  Also the last item in the module  is automatically "returned", you do not need `Return`.  (`Return` is *extremely* rarely used in mathematica )

Comment: And use == instead of = inside NDSolve[{Y'[t] == a*Y[t] + b*X[t],  X'[t] == c*Y[t] + a*X[t], Y[t1] == y1i, X[t1] == y2i} And eliminate the ` at the end of your last line. With the changes from agentp and this then your code seems to run fine.